# Cardinality of Set of Rooted Spanning Trees of Integer Lattice

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am wondering whether there are countably many or uncountably many spanning trees of the integer lattice rooted at a particular vertex, say the origin.

In a spanning tree rooted at the origin there is a unique path from each vertex to the origin. There are countably many paths to the origin for each vertex, and each spanning tree is uniquely determined by the paths for each vertex in the integer lattice. There are uncountably many ways to choose a path for each vertex, but not every choice of paths will correspond to a spanning tree, so this doesn't help in determining whether there are countably many or uncountably many.

Any help would be appreciated.